# Hey My bootstrap file is not working after given correct file path. It doesn't apply on my page

Tags: php, html, css, bootstrap-4

This is the file path

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

I tried all the possible ways but couldn't fix the problem. Browser console says `err_abborted 404`

Comment: Maybe its `<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/bootstrap.min.css">` give a screenshot of your files tree

Comment: Welcome at StackOverflow. Please improve your question or it will be closed. Read about  [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), Especially, what did you try to debug?

Comment: 404 means the path was obviously _not_ correct …

Comment: Use **Inspector Tool** of your browser, probably Network tab, it will give you a clue what's wrong. We don't know your structure, however, you need to realize that is the difference between `href="../relative/` and  `href="/absolute/` paths according to your root.

Comment: Inspector tool shows net::ERR_ABORTED 404(Not Found)

Comment: What should I do now  my bootstrap file is in css folder & the page where I am writing my code is in another folder but both have same root folder

Answer (score 0):

As said above it depends on the structure of your files how you should write the filepath (and is it linked in the head?). But have you tried to link it to BoostrapCDN, without the `../` like in this 'Get started documents example'? https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/getting-started/introduction/
Hope it works out!